# Hyperlinking in Google sheets via a loop

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, hyperlink, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am attempting to create a loop for the creation of hyperlinks depending on the cell content.

E.g if I have cells with the following content:

```
490
545
546
494
495
496
```

I would like to produce a loop which automates a hyperlink ending in the cell content which hyperlinks the cell itself e.g.:

```
mysite.com/app/?q=22&id=490
mysite.com/app/?q=22&id=545
mysite.com/app/?q=22&id=546
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far to achieve this? At the moment your question just has a requirement with no attempt to solve it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A1:A), "mysite.com/app/?q=22&id="&A1:A, ))
```

[image: 0]